# Not exported function cannot be used or it is Ok?

Tags: r

In R package there may be some not exported functions which can only access by `package name:::function name`. These functions were not exported by the author of the package. Is that mean we cannot access them in anyway because the copyright? What about if I really need to based my work on these functions? Any help please?

Comment: @Rich Scriven Yes I access them. But as I am a phd student I am doing a research and really need to use these functions inside my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions that are not exported are usually internal helper functions for the package. These are not normally meant for general usage. It should be fine to use them, but there may be little or no documentation about them.

Comment: I do not need a documentation, I understand them but I just fared if we allowed by the license to use them or not?

Comment: The internal functions share the same license as the overall package, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: They are use General public license (GPL)

Comment: Is that mean the GPL is free and we allowd to use the functions.

Comment: If the package is GPL, then the non-exported functions are also GPL. You are free to use them.

Comment: @Kevin in conformance with the restrictions of the license. The functions' source code is not public domain.